# Java Parse String to Double Overflow Check

Tags: java, double

I'm writing a calculator demo. The calculator takes user inputs (String) and do some calculation. The first step is to parse strings to double.

I'm using  `NumberUtils.isParsable()` and `Double.parseDouble()`. However, I'd like to limit user input so that the double number does not overflow. It seems that `parseDouble()` only checks if the string is a number. I didn't find any method that checks the string's value.

I wonder what is the best way to do so.

Comment: Enclosing the call to `Double.parseDouble()` in a try-catch block is a reasonable thing to do, and would let you handle any sort of errors which might take place.

Comment: Convert back to String to check if the double overflow. `String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(a)).equal(a)`

Comment: @PatrickChen That won't work. `"0.50"` will become `"0.5"`. Some numbers will get rounded due to loss of precision (that is different from an overflow).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Double.parseDouble does not throw exceptions for overflow, it returns Double.Infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that "overflow" is talking about a number that is too large to represent.

If you call `Double.parseDouble()` on a "really large number", you will actually get an INF value ... not an exception<sup>1</sup>.  So the simple solution<sup>2</sup> to numbers that overflow is to use `Double.isInfinite(double)` to test the result of calling `Double.parseDouble(String)`.

It will be more efficient AND less code to do the conversion and test the result that to (try to) check before doing the test.

---

<sup>1 - I checked the Java 11 source code.  Look at the code for `jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal`.  The comments are kind of amusing.</sup>

<sup>2 - If you are a graduate of the "exceptions are evil" school of thinking, you could use a regex to check the syntax of the string before calling `parseDouble`.  My opinion is that it is unnecessary.  Just handle the exception.</sup>

Comment: "1.7976931348623158E308" is greater than `Double.MAX_VALUE` but does not produce a result of infinite when you do `Double.parseDouble("1.7976931348623158E308")` instead you get `Double.MAX_VALUE`

Comment: 1.7976931348623158E308 is within rounding error of Double.MAX_VALUE which (according to Wikipedia) is 1.7976931348623157E308.  If you really care about things to this level of precision, you should be using `BigDecimal` throughout.  The conversion computation that `Double.parseDouble` does uses the `double` type ... I think.

Comment: Bottom line is that 1.7976931348623158E308 has not overflowed in the context of the Java implementation of `double` and string -> double conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `BigDecimal` class to check the input against the maximum value for a `double`.

Here's a method that will return `true` if the provided `String` represents a numerical value that is less than or equal to the maximum value for a `double` and return `false` when the input is larger than the maximum value a `double` can represent.

```
public static boolean isValidDouble(String input){
    final BigDecimal MAX_DOUBLE = new BigDecimal(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    try{
        BigDecimal bigInput = new BigDecimal(input);
        return bigInput.compareTo(MAX_DOUBLE) < 1;
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is some code to test the above method:

```
    String[] inputs = {
            "1E999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999",
            "1234",
            "1.7976931348623157E308",
            "1.79769313486231570E308",
            "1.79769313486231571E308",
            "1.79769313486231569E308",
            "1E400"
    };

    for(String input: inputs){
        System.out.println("input is: "+input);
        System.out.println("is valid double? " + String.valueOf(isValidDouble(input)));
    }
```

Here is the resulting output from the above tests:

```
input is: 1E999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
is valid double? false
input is: 1234
is valid double? true
input is: 1.7976931348623157E308
is valid double? true
input is: 1.79769313486231570E308
is valid double? true
input is: 1.79769313486231571E308
is valid double? false
input is: 1.79769313486231569E308
is valid double? true
input is: 1E400
is valid double? false
```